# Remove Hash when reloading page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hash, reload

Im using a hash to switch through my image slider.
when i reload the page and the hash is set to e.h. #3
there is no picture. when the gallery slides automatically after some seconds
it shows the next one... so for a few seconds there is nothing.

is there a way to check for a hash when loading the page and remove it?
i just want to care about the persons who bookmark the page with the hash.

Greetings.

edited: hashtag --> hash (thank you.)

Comment: Just a nitpick: "hashtag" is strictly a Twitter thing, alternative names for what you refer to include simply "hash" or "hash fragment".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
location.hash = ""
```

Run that on page load.