# jQuery How to remove hash and last click function on reload

Tags: jquery

**UPDATED**
I have created an one page design. I am using JQuery for the menu and hashtags. Now I was figure out how I can remove the # hash when the user is reloading the page and reset the function to go to that specific section.

So when the user is at the section `video` the url is: `www.mydomein.com/#video`. I was searching how I can remove the `#video` when the user is refreshing the page and stay at the top of the page, and not go to the part that was clicked before the reload. How can I fix this?

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/12/

Comment: Do you just want the user to begin at the top after a refresh?

Comment: It seems this has already been answered. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7894905/1182899

Comment: @Vasil, OP is trying to remove that on refresh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Hash when reloading page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894859/remove-hash-when-reloading-page)

Answer (score 1):

No idea how to do this via jQuery but plain JavaScript can do that too:

```
<body onload="location.hash='';">
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onbeforeunload = function () { location.hash=""; };
</script>
```

You can include it anywhere, since it is plain javascript and is independent.